# linux kernel output in a file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am using a program by using the linux kernel (in this case a predictor for protein localization). The output/results are printed in the linux kernel, one after each other. However, if I want to copy it to a simple textfile, the "length" of the kernel is not long enough for all the results.

instead of using smaller seperate files, I would like to print the output of the kernel to a file. I tried to google this, but it doesn't really help me futher.
1. dmesg seems to be for system-output stuff?
2. the /var/log/syslog.txt doesn't show the stuff I need, but other technical kernel stuff.
3. i saw something with printf(), but didn't quite understand the mechanics and if it was useable for my problem.

could someone explain how to do this or where to look for the right info?

Comment: How exactly is this program doing the printing?

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
results and more stuff
>> prediction for YLR073C_Q08003_Saccharomyces is nuc (k=23)

Comment: I think i found out how to do it, by using > fileToBeNamed.txt at the end of the command, Sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found out how to do it, by using > fileToBeNamed.txt at the end of the command, Sorry :(